# Prevent http login in Moodle when https login is enabled

Tags: apache, security, authentication, https, moodle

I enabled *Use HTTPS for logins* in *HTTP Security*. It works fine when I enter root address (mymoodlewebsite.com). Unfortunately it is possible to login through unsecured connection in two cases:

1. When session expires - Moodle asks for credentials via http login page (http:// (...) /login/index.php)
2. It is possible to change protocol in address bar from https to http.

After login communication is not encrypted (It should be this way).
I use Debian/Apache server.

What should I do to eliminate possibility of insecure login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could resolve this problem by using an Apache redirect. Create a file in `login` folder and name it `.htaccess`, then insert these lines:

```
# HTTP 301 redirect
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/login/login\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login/login.php
```

You must have the rewrite module enabled, otherwise this solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your `moodle/config.php` file

```
$CFG->loginhttps=false;
```